# Use REST calls in Hybris

Tags: rest, sap-commerce-cloud

I've installed `Hybris 6.4` and I want to make use of its secured `RESTful` access to all `Hybris` models, that comes with the `platformwebservices`.

In order to have access to the `REST API`, i.e. requests like `http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries`, I need to [configure the OAuth 2.0](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/OAuth+2.0.)

I think, I need to understand what values I need to provide in the headers:
 `client_id=...&client_secret=...&grant_type=...&username=...&password=...`?

Comment: Did you run ant extgen selecting ycommecerwebservices template?

Answer (score 0):

To test, you can simply use `basic authentication` with username/password (`admin/***`). In [`postman`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) select `basic authentication` with username and password (Update request).

Find sample request from [wiki](https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8b544baa86691014aa8af0140b6adc0d.html).

Comment: I am doing 
**GET /rest/oauth/token?client_id={client_defined}&secret={secret_defined}&grant_type=password&username={customer_name}&password={pass}**

and receive an HMTL response:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>hybris administration console | Login</title>
...
   <div id="logincontrols" class="logincontrols">
    <div id="loginErrors">&nbsp;

    </div>
...
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>`

And whatever REST request I try I wlways get the same HTML response.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Webservices are getting authenticated using the configuration in security-spring.xml.

```
    <oauth:client client-id="client-side" resource-ids="hybris" authorized-grant-types="implicit,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" secret="secret" redirect-uri="http://localhost:9001/rest/oauth2_implicit_callback" />
        <oauth:client client-id="mobile_android" resource-ids="hybris"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,refresh_token,password,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" secret="secret"
            redirect-uri="http://localhost:9001/rest/oauth2_callback" />
        <oauth:client client-id="trusted_client" resource-ids="hybris"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,refresh_token,password,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
            secret="secret" />
```

These are the different client-id and secret codes available by default.